# How to access a class's getter and setter methods through another generic way in C ++

Tags: c++

I would like to be able to assign and / or retrieve values of an object through another class, where I could declare which properties I would like to access, their types, the method for accessing the value of the private attribute and the method for assigning the value.

I would like to store in a hash the name of the property and the methods to manipulate the value, in this way I could use the generic form the values of the class by other entities, but I don't know if it is possible (I imagine so), and I don't know how to do .

The code below is not functional, it was based on an attempt I was making to implement a solution. One of the error is:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'Test<unsigned int>::Test(C&, const char [2], unsigned int (C::*)() const, void (C::*)(unsigned int))'
     auto t1 = new Test<unsigned int>(c, "a", &C::getA, &C::setA);
```

Below the code snippet

```
#include <string>
#include <map>

class C {
public:
    unsigned int getA() const {
        return a;
    }

    void setA(unsigned int value) {
        C::a = value;
    }

    const std::string &getB() {
        return b;
    }

    void setB(const std::string &value) {
        C::b = value;
    }

private:
    unsigned int a;
    std::string b;
};

template<typename T>
class Test {
public:
    Test(T t, const std::string attribute, const T (*getter)(), void (*setter)(T)) : t(t), attribute(attribute),
                                                                                      getter(getter), setter(setter) {}

    const std::string &getAttribute() const {
        return attribute;
    }

private:
    T t;
    std::string attribute;

    const T (*getter)();

    void (*setter)(T t);
};


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    C c;
    auto t1 = new Test<unsigned int>(c, "a", &C::getA, &C::setA);
    auto t2 = new Test<std::string>(c, "b", &C::getB, &C::setB);
    std::map<std::string, std::string *> map;
    
    map.insert({t1.getAttribute, t1});
    map.insert({t2.getAttribute, t2});
}
```

So basically I have two questions, is it possible to do this? if so, how?

In this context for example if I needed to retrieve the value of "a" (variable) t1, I would like to go to the map and use the function pointer of the test class getter.

Based on this I will implement parser functions for json among others.

Comment: `Test<std::string>` and `Test<unsigned int>` are unrelated classes (even if generated from same template). So you cannot insert them in same container without some type erasure.

Comment: As for "No matching function to call" error I would try to use template constructor that stores lambdas or std::bind from member function pointers. In this case you can keep "this" pointer in functor context.

Comment: you need an object to call a member function. pointers to free functions are not the same as pointers to memebr functions

Comment: if this is to parse some json, why use getters and setters? Isnt a `std::map< attribute_name, std::string>` simpler?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 There will be other samples, will be class too, will not be just using std and primitive types. A method for example unserializer, would receive a Json:Value would retrieve the property and already setter the class for primitive types.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar; I have many variables (of different types) that I want to modify through a single interface. I pass a string, and my class will translate it to a value to assign to the connected variable.

I first create a class with a virtual function:

```cpp
struct param_assign_base
{       
    virtual void assign(void* param, const char* value) = 0;
};

// Declare the concrete class.
template<typename p_type>
struct param_assign;
```

Then I create specialized instances of this, for example for a `bool` type variable:

```cpp
template<>
struct param_assign<bool> : param_assign_base
{
    void assign(void* param, const char* value)
    {
        *static_cast<bool*>(param) = extract_bool(value);
    }

    bool extract_bool(const char* value)
    {
        // make a return value that will be assigned to the connected variable.
    }
};
```

Then I populate a map:

```cpp
using param_map_type = std::map<
    std::string, 
    std::pair<void*, params::param_assign_base*>>;

param_map_type populate()
{
    param_map_type param_map;
    param_map["a"] = std::make_pair(&a, new param_assign<bool>);
    param_map["b"] = std::make_pair(&b, new param_assign<char*>);
    param_map["c"] = std::make_pair(&c, new param_assign<int>);

    // a more proper design wouldn't use new, it would 
    // use std::make_unique to avoid memory leaks.
}
```

Then I use a constructed `param_map` variable to assign variables like:

```cpp
param_map["a"].second->assign(param_map["a"].first, value_to_assign);
```

The above line can also be put in a function so you avoid repeating `param_map["a"]`.

The disadvantage of this design is that you won't be able to access the variable unless you can explicitly cast its type when you do `param_map["a"]`, as in that form its just a void pointer. When you use a map, each entry needs to have the same type, so its not possible for the map to distinguish types.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a `parameter` type that type-erases what is stored within it.

```
class parameter {
    struct impl_base {
        virtual void assign(std::string_view value) = 0;
        virtual std::string get() const = 0;
    };
    template <typename T>
    struct impl : impl_base {
        T & obj;
        impl(T & value) : obj(value) {}

        void assign(std::string_view value) {
            obj = from_string<T>(value);
        }
        std::string get() const {
            return to_string(obj);
        }
    };
    template<typename C, typename T>
    struct member_impl {
        C & obj;
        T (C::*get)();
        void (C::*set)(T);
        impl(C & value, T (C::*get)(), void(C::*set)(T))
         : obj(value), get(get), set(set) {}

        void assign(std::string_view value) {
            (obj.*set)(from_string<T>(value));
        }
        std::string get() const {
            return to_string((obj.*get)());
        }
    };

    std::unique_ptr<impl_base> pimpl;
public:
    template <typename T>
    parameter(T& value) : pimpl(std::make_unique<impl<T>>(value)) {}
    template <typename C, typename T>
    parameter(T& value, T (C::*get)(), void(C::*set)(T))
     : pimpl(std::make_unique<member_impl<T>>(value, get, set)) {}

    void assign(std::string_view value) {
        pimpl->assign(value);
    }
    std::string get() const {
        return pimpl->get();
    }
};
```

You need to be careful with how your getters and setters are defined. Your `&C::getA` is of type `unsigned int (C::*)() const`, which is a type distinct from `unsigned int (C::*)()`, which is what you declare.

```
class C {
public:
    unsigned int a;

    std::string getB() {
        return b;
    }

    void setB(std::string value) {
        C::b = value;
    }

private:
    std::string b;
};
```

Alternatively, you can use `std::function<T(const C &)>` as your `get` type, `std::function<void(C &, const T &)>` as your `set` type, and use `std::mem_fn` to wrap `&C::getFoo` and `&C::setFoo`

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    C c;
    std::map<std::string, parameter> map;
    
    map.emplace("a", c.a);
    map.emplace("b", c, &C::getB, &C::setB);
}
```

The last thing is to fill out `from_string<T>` and `to_string<T>` free functions for each type you store.